# SharePoint 2010: What parameter are available for CreatePage.aspx

Tags: url, sharepoint-2010

I would like to call `CreatePage.aspx` with some parameters like the Title... but unfortunately the only one I certainly know is `LayoutName`.

Does anyone know other parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass "List" GUID to specify the destination page library
You can also pass "RootFolder" to specify the folder structure into which the page should be saved.